# multiple menu items with active class

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

This is driving me nuts. I'm creating a flask app and use Bootstrap (latest version) for a lot of css and js things. With this bootstrap comes a js function to add an active class to the menu item you last clicked. This works fine for the majority of the menu, but in some cases 2 items have the active class added.

css:

```
.nav-sidebar > .active > a { color: #fff; background-color: #428bca;}
```

html:

```
            <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="11">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="12">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="13">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="14">6</a></li>
```

Yes, the urls are actually numbers in my app. what happens is the following: The active class works fine 1, 2, 5, and 6.
When clicking on 3, nr 1 also is active, and when clicking on 4, nr 2 is also active. 
Why? the only similarity I see is the last number in the url, but that couldn't be causing this issue, could it?

Comment: can you edit your post to include a code snippet that shows this? It would be a lot easier to help you with that included.

Comment: Pretty sure you nailed it... most likely your code is somehow only looking at the last number, but until we see other code, particularly the JS code we won't know.

Comment: Let me find out that part from bootstrap first. I'll come back on that asap

Answer (score 1):

well, found out that it was actually a ninja macro causing this issue.

`{% macro nav_link(endpoint, name) %} {% if request.endpoint.endswith(endpoint) %} <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for(endpoint) }}">{{name}}</a></li> {% else %}   <li><a href="{{ url_for(endpoint) }}">{{name}}</a></li> {% endif %} {% endmacro %}`

I changed the if statement to check on everything after the slash, that solved the issue.